# Two simple HTML & CSS questions

Tags: html, css

A portion of a text seems to climb out of the page boundaries. Why is that?
What happens to text if 'auto' value is assigned to overflow property, to the element containing the text?

Comment: Show image or code.

Comment: If you post your code (CSS, HTML) and a screenshot of the issue, people will be able to help more easily

Answer (score 0):

Overflow property is used to add a scrollView to a big text within small space. Auto will decide if you tag needs a scrollBar or not. Try setting a height to your text or body.